# Maven command prompt run tomcat debug mode (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, maven, debugging, tomcat

I have got a Java web application project what use Maven, Spring, Tomcat, and so on. 
I use Eclipse Mars and I can import the project but I cannot run it under Eclipse because there are some plug-ins which I cannot find. But I can compile the project with `mvn compile` command and I can run my project with `mvn tomcat7:run` command. 
I want to run the project in debug mode but I don't know how to run the project in debug mode from command prompt. I know that there is an mvnDebug command but if I put a breakpoint anywhere in my source (naturally somewhere in Java file) code in Eclipse, it stops when the process reach the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you have m2e eclipse, go to `Debug Configuration > Goals : mvn tomcat7:run > Apply > Debug`